# Invalid column name "User_Id"

Tags: c#

I'm getting this exception about a column "User_Id" which I don't have anywhere in my database or in my code. It just showed up like that... What is the problem ? Any suggestions ? I get this exception when I want to add something.

```
        protected override void BaseAdd(Meal entity)
        {
            using (var context = new ProjectContext())
            {
                context.Meals.Add(entity);
                context.SaveChanges(); //here is where I get the exception
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is there an id/primary key column in the Meals table?

Comment: Do a search across your entire solution for `User_Id` - it's almost certainly present somewhere. But we have no chance of locating it, based on your presented code.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It is very possible that there will be no `User_Id` anywhere in code. See my answer.

Comment: Check Your Edmx file, it may be the case that column was present at the time of creating edmx and now it is deleted from the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have User_Id because you mapped that `User` can have multiple `Meals` in your POCO like so.

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Meal> Meals { get; set; }
}
```

Because of that EF automatically assumes that `Meal` will have 1-many relations with `User`.

I suggest you first do `update-database -v -f` to make sure your database is set up properly. And second - I strongly advise making relational-ids also in your POCO so your database is 1-1 with your POCO and you won't get any surprises like these.